# How to scrape address from websites using Scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I am using Scrapy and I need to scrape the address from contact us page from a given domain. The domains are provided as a result of google search api and hence I do not know what the exact structure of the web page is going to be. Is this kind of scraping possible? Any examples would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Providing few examples would help to make a better answer, but the general idea could be to:

- find the "Contact Us" link
- follow the link and extract the address

assuming you don't have any information about the web-sites you'll be given.

Let's focus on the first problem.

The main problem here is that the web-sites are structured differently and, strictly speaking, you cannot build a 100% reliable way to find the "Contact Us" page. But, you can "cover" the most common cases:

- follow the `a` tag with the text "Contact Us", "Contact", "About Us", "About" etc
- check `/about`, `/contact_us` and similar endpoints, examples:

  - http://www.sample.com/contact.php
  - http://www.sample.com/contact
- follow all links that have `contact`, `about` etc text inside

From these you can build a set of [`Rules`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule) for your [`CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider).

The second problem is no easier - you don't know where on the page an address is located (and may be it doesn't exist on a page), and you don't know the address format. You may need to dive into [Natural Language Processing](http://www.nltk.org/) and [Machine Learning](http://scikit-learn.org/).

Comment: So you suggest first tracking down the contact us page and then look for address on that page. Do you think a regex to locate the pincode would be a good idea?

Comment: @DharmanshuKamra it is possible, but might not be easy to write an expression that would support all the possible address formats. Difficult to tell more. Hope that helps.